# How to make a button on a form be enabled from a different form?

Tags: c#, button

Im making a game with a menu that opens new forms for each level. When you complete a level, it is supposed to congratulate you through a message box (it does) and then enable the next level's button on the different menu form. So I accessed the designer and made the buttons public and tried:

```
new LevelMenu().button2.Enabled = true;
```

But that didn't work.
I also tried doing:

```
public event Action levelCompleted;
//then down lower i did (after it is declared that you won the level):
if (levelCompleted != null)
    levelCompleted();
W1L1.levelCompleted += () => LevelMenu.button2.Enabled = true;
```

But that give me the error of:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'The_Levels.W1L1.levelCompleted'

The form i'm working with is "W1L1", and "LevelMenu" is the menu form. Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of W1L1.levelCompleted += () => LevelMenu.button2.Enabled = true; try public event Action levelCompleted = () => LevelMenu.button2.Enabled = true; (without +). Did it work>?

Comment: Remove the last line and initialize "levelCompleted" on the first as shown on previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a reference to your instance of **LevelMenu**.
So when you create your "W1L1" form, you might just pass the *LevelMenu* to it.

```
public class W1L1
{
    private readonly LevelMenu _levelMenu;

    public W1L1(LevelMenu levelMenu)
    {
        this._levelMenu = levelMenu;
    }

    //Where you want to enable the button
    this._levelMenu.button2.Enabled = true;
}
```

It's not the best solution, in an architectural way, but it works.

But it would be better if you create a more OOP way for enabling the button of the next level.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the next level open it as a separate object as a new form.  Now when the level is completed you can access the public controls on that form from the originating class.  Something like this might help:

```
LevelMenu NextLevel = new LevelMenu();
public event Action levelCompleted;
if (levelCompleted != null)
    levelCompleted();
NextLevel.button2.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what I did I hope this helps

I created 2 Forms

Form1 = where menu is (buttons), Form2 = the game level (i.e. level 1)

then in Form2 I added an even LevelCompleted that will notify form1 that the player completed the level

```
  //add this to form2
  //the delegate 
  public delegate void LevelCompleted(Int32 level);

  //the event
  public event LevelCompleted LevelCompletedEvent;
```

then on Form1 (the menu form) when you create an instance of Form2 (which has the event) subscribe to it and create a handler, in my case I added it after i created the instance of Form2

```
  private void button1_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Form2 level1 = new Form2();
    level1.LevelCompletedEvent += new Form2.LevelCompleted(level1_LevelCompletedHandler);
    level1.Show();
   }

   //and this is the handler method
   void level1_LevelCompletedHandler(int level)
   {
      //the logic for controlling the button states
      // the level parameter can be used to indicate what is the current level completed.
      if(level == 1)
      {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
      }
     }
```

Note: that in Form2 (the game level) I created a field gameOver that can be used if he did not complete the game
   If in case he is permitted to go to next level, You must raise the event in this form to notify Form1 (the menu)
   that he (the user) completed the level and Form1 will execute the method level1_LevelCompletedHandler(int level).

I know this is not well explained but I hope I can give you an idea on the event.